# AES-CBC and SHA-512 hash Encryption with C++ produces odd output

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes, sha

**EDIT**
This question has been half answered through comments. I was successful in getting the encryption with both AES and SHA to work successfully. The problem with SHA was simple - I was hashing in Java with uppercase hex and C++ with lowercase. AES was successful after changing the type from string to unsigned char and using memcpy instead of strcpy.. I'm still interested in understanding why, *after encryption*, the result contained the original message in plaintext alongside the binary data - regardless of the type that I was using.

I am currently working on a project in C++ that requires encryption. Normally, I would use Java for this task, however, due to software requirements I have chose C++. After creating an Encryption class with the openssl library, I ran a simple test with AES-CBC 256. The test was a Hello World message encrypted by a hex string key and IV followed by the encrypted result being decrypted. The output below shows the results.

[image]

After encryption the binary data contains the original string in plain text as well as the hex value present in the encrypted hex string. After decryption the original hex value for the message is shown in the output as if the process worked.

I am also having problems with creating a SHA-512 hash. Creating a hash in Java differs from the one created in C++. Creating a SHA-256 Hmac hash, however, produces the same output in both languages.

Below is the C++ code I am using in the encryption class.

```
std::string Encryption::AES::cbc256(const char* data, ssize_t len, const char* key, const char* iv, bool encrypt) {

    std::string keyStr = key;
    std::string ivStr = iv;
    std::string dataStr = data;

    std::string _keyStr = Encryption::Utils::fromHex(keyStr.c_str(), 64);
    std::string _ivStr = Encryption::Utils::fromHex(ivStr.c_str(), 32);
    std::string _dataStr = Encryption::Utils::fromHex(dataStr.c_str(), dataStr.size());

    size_t inputLength = len;

    char aes_input[_dataStr.size()];
    char aes_key[32];

    memset(aes_input, 0, _dataStr.size());
    memset(aes_key, 0, sizeof(aes_key));

    strcpy(aes_input, _dataStr.c_str());
    strcpy(aes_key, _keyStr.c_str());

    char aes_iv[16];
    memset(aes_iv, 0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    strcpy(aes_iv, _ivStr.c_str());

    const size_t encLength = ((inputLength + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    if(encrypt) {

        char res[inputLength];

        AES_KEY enc_key;
        AES_set_encrypt_key((unsigned char*) aes_key, 256, &enc_key);
        AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char*) aes_input, (unsigned char *) res, inputLength, &enc_key, (unsigned char *) aes_iv, AES_ENCRYPT);

        return Encryption::Utils::toHex((unsigned char *) res, strlen(res));

    } else {

        char res[inputLength];

        AES_KEY enc_key;
        AES_set_decrypt_key((unsigned char*) aes_key, 256, &enc_key);
        AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char*) aes_input, (unsigned char *) res, inputLength, &enc_key, (unsigned char *) aes_iv, AES_DECRYPT);

        return Encryption::Utils::toHex((unsigned char *) res, strlen(res));

    }

}

std::string Encryption::SHA::hash512(const char *source) {

    std::string input = source;

    unsigned char hash[64];
    SHA512_CTX sha512;
    SHA512_Init(&sha512);
    SHA512_Update(&sha512, input.c_str(), input.size());
    SHA512_Final(hash, &sha512);

    std::stringstream ss;

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(hash); i++) {

        ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int) hash[i];

    }

    return ss.str();

}

std::string Encryption::Utils::fromHex(const char* source, ssize_t size) {

    int _size = size / 2;

    char* dest = new char[_size];

    std::string input = source;
    int x=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<_size; i++) {

        std::string ret = "";
        for(int y=0; y<2; y++) {
            ret += input.at(x);
            x++;
        }

        std::stringstream  ss;
        ss << std::hex << ret;
        unsigned int j;
        ss >> j;

        dest[i] = (char) static_cast<int>(j);

    }


    return std::string(dest);

}
```

Can anyone explain to me, or offer their help, as to why I am getting the output I am getting?

Comment: `strcpy(aes_iv, _ivStr.c_str());` and `strcpy(aes_key, _keyStr.c_str());` look wrong.  Neither an AES key nor an AES/CBC IV are C-style strings.

Comment: C-style strings (and the `const char*` pointer returned by the `c_str()` member function of `std::string`) are by convention terminated at the first null-character (`'\0'`), thus are not suitable to hold arbitrary binary data. The `std::string` class theoretically can hold any bytes (even embedded `'\0'` characters), but by practical convention, is not OK to use as a binary data container. For that, use the `std::vector` container: e.g., `std::vector<std::byte>` or, as OpenSSL seems to expect pointers of type `unsigned char*`, use `std::vector<unsigned char>` and then its `data()` function.

Comment: Why are you using the low level AES functions? Those e.g. don't supply any padding. You're much better off using OpenSSL EVP_ functions, especially if your processor supports AES encryption / decryption functionality in hardware - most processors by now.